# Trying to understand JSTween basics

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstween

I'm sitting here now for about three hours trying to make a simple Animation with JSTween.
I found a few threads where I got examples for what I'm trying to do (for Example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317297/jstween-library-broken)) but it just doesn't work.
For sure it's just some "when you see it" failure.
Would be nice if one of you would have a look on the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7t5La/).

### HTML

```
<body>
  <ul id="slides">
    <li id="left">
    </li>
    <li id="center">
    </li>
    <li id="right">
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var left = $('#left'),
      center = $('#center'),
      right = $('#right');


  center.click(function(){  
    left.tween({
      left:{
        start: -500,
        stop: 0,
        time: 0,
        duration: 3,
        units: 'px',
        effect: 'easeInOut' 
      }
    });
  $.play();
  });
});
```

Thanks
Spyrko

Comment: What is the problem you didn't say what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

`$(window).load(function(){`

Use:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

I amended your JSFiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7t5La/3/